# Preferred way of creating problem and solution environments

Tags: environments, theorems

I know we can create problem-solution pairs using the `exercise` package but I am looking for something that is much simpler and similar to `theorem` and `proof` environments. I have solved this problem in two different ways.

## Using 'theorem' and 'proof' environments

Here is one way to write a problem statement followed by a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Problem}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc quis
volutpat tellus. Morbi dapibus dolor quis ligula porta eget adipiscing
nibh consectetur. Nulla fringilla dolor id elit vulputate ac posuere
ligula auctor.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}[Solution]
Ut at turpis felis. Donec venenatis fermentum volutpat.
Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla fringilla adipiscing metus, eget porta
turpis facilisis vel. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus tristique ultricies
imperdiet. Cras non sapien erat, et tincidunt enim. Praesent vel ipsum
elit. Donec tincidunt, sem vitae scelerisque volutpat, diam dui
elementum est, quis ullamcorper libero sapien laoreet sem. 
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The output is shown below.

[image: theorem environment]

## Using custom 'problem' and 'solution' environments

This problem can also be solved by defining my own environments as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{problem}[1][Problem]
{\begin{trivlist} \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1.}] \itshape}
{\end{trivlist}}

\newenvironment{solution}[1][Solution]
{\begin{trivlist} \item[\hskip \labelsep {\itshape #1.}]}
{\end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc quis
volutpat tellus. Morbi dapibus dolor quis ligula porta eget adipiscing
nibh consectetur. Nulla fringilla dolor id elit vulputate ac posuere
ligula auctor.
\end{problem}

\begin{solution}[Solution]
Ut at turpis felis. Donec venenatis fermentum volutpat.
Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla fringilla adipiscing metus, eget porta
turpis facilisis vel. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus tristique ultricies
imperdiet. Cras non sapien erat, et tincidunt enim. Praesent vel ipsum
elit. Donec tincidunt, sem vitae scelerisque volutpat, diam dui
elementum est, quis ullamcorper libero sapien laoreet sem. 
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

The output is shown below.

[image: custom environment]

I have three questions about this.

1. What is the preferred way of solving this problem? Which one of the two methods above is a better way of solving this problem?
2. Would you suggest any improvements or modifications to the `problem` and `solution` environments I have defined in the second method?
3. The two outputs are very similar but they are not exactly similar. If you open [the first output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2sng.png) and [the second output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guP1v.png) in two different tabs of the browser and switch between them, you can see some differences. Why do these differences occur?

   - Different spacing between characters in the italicized text.
   - Different vertical space between the problem and solution.

Comment: I prefer the 1st option. You can also use `\theoremstyle` provided by `amsthm` package to format you block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first approach has two disadvantages:

- Semantically it is somehow ambiguous since you are using a `proof` environment and have to change the default name used in the label; I think it's better to have a dedicated environment with a name `solution` (or closer to solution than `proof`).
- Using the defalut `proof` environment from `amsthm`, you need to redefine `\qedsymbol` so that the end mark won't appear in your modified environment.

Your second approach has one potential drawback illustrated by the vertical spacing issue you noticed; if you use the `\trivlist` approach for these two environments but eventually use some environments from the `amsthm` package, the spacing might result inconsistent.

I would probably opt for a mixture of your approaches; I would use `\theoremstyle` from the `amsthm` package to define a style for solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem*{problem}{Problem}
\newtheoremstyle{solution}%
  {\topsep}{\topsep}{\normalfont}{}%
  {\itshape}{.}{5pt}{}
\theoremstyle{solution}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc quis
volutpat tellus. Morbi dapibus dolor quis ligula porta eget adipiscing
nibh consectetur. Nulla fringilla dolor id elit vulputate ac posuere
ligula auctor.
\end{problem}

\begin{solution}
Ut at turpis felis. Donec venenatis fermentum volutpat.
Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla fringilla adipiscing metus, eget porta
turpis facilisis vel. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus tristique ultricies
imperdiet. Cras non sapien erat, et tincidunt enim. Praesent vel ipsum
elit. Donec tincidunt, sem vitae scelerisque volutpat, diam dui
elementum est, quis ullamcorper libero sapien laoreet sem. 
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding your third question, when I ran your example codes, I couldn't reproduce any different spacing between characters in the italicized text (but the images you linked effectively show a difference, so that makes me wonder how did you run your examples?). The difference in spacing comes from the default settings for vertical spacing around a theorem-structure defined using `amsthm`.