# What is a good environment for writing problems and solutions?

Tags: macros, packages, environments, answers, questionnaire

I'm writing a book where I record interesting problems and their solutions.

However, there does not seem to be an organized list, or other reference to these types of latex packages and tex macros. Is there such a listing? And if not, what are the available packages for the question and answer format, and what are their respective merits and features?

I'm new to this, so advice on how to define my own environment would be greatly appreciated, if none of the packages designed for question and answer work well.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (MWE) which demonstrates your situation and what you have tried. It matters a very great deal which class you are using, for example, and what a typical problem/solution pair looks like in terms of content, length etc.

Comment: Try a quick search in the box at top right.  `"Question and Answer"` gave me so many hits, that it certainly should give you a starting point for a MWE that at least approximates the style you might feel comfortable with.

Comment: `exsheets` is probably best for you, but this is opinion-based.

Comment: The number of hits for `question and answer` are 7021. An answer to this question could be helpful to users.

Comment: You might post a (mocked up) image of your ideal question and answer environment to give others an idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71203/90087

Comment: See this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286087/4778

Comment: @Alenanno that is really very nicely done.